# Importing data with bcp

Tags: cmd, sql-server-2014, bcp

I would like to import data in the file 'c:_value_.txt' to my database like this

```
Bcp mydb.mytable in 'C:\_value_.txt' -T -c -Smypc\instancename
```

However I keep getting the error
Unable to open BCP host data -file
Why is this?

Comment: You are not providing a path in your data_file. Try `Bcp mydb.mytable in 'C:\_value_.txt' -T -c -Smypc\instancename`

Comment: That gives the same error as well. It is what I had started with

Comment: `Bcp mydb.mytable in 'C:\_value_.txt' -T -c -S mypc\instancename`, so add a space between `-S` and the `servername\instancename`.

Comment: Also have you checked [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic237238-8-1.aspx) on sqlservercentral.com?

Comment: Same error, read the forum thread and posted there as well

Comment: Maybe the Windows account doesn't have permissions on the folder?

Comment: Try create a folder named `folder` on the C drive, and use `C:\folder\_value_.txt` (or any other directory name under the C drive)

Comment: Also try changing the extension to `.dat` instead of `.txt`

Comment: Oh, also lose the single quotes around the filename. Either use no quotes, or use double quotes (`""`) if the name contains spaces and such

Comment: Well I can read the file unless bcp uses a different account... Gave user group everyone full control and still  same problem

Comment: I gave about all the ideas I had... perhaps you can edit your question and add `sql-server` to your tag list for better visibility so other people can chime in.

Comment: Removing single quotes solved it!! Thanks

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer so I get some extra credibility points? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the single quotes around the filename. Either use no quotes, or use double quotes ("") if the name contains spaces and such.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the single quotes was able to solve this